# JDBC query with vector<String> as WHERE part

Tags: sql, list, jdbc, vector

I have a table MYTABLE with a column STRINGCOL of string constants.
I further have a Vector, lets call it theVector, with a subset of those constants in STRINGCOL.

I want to write such a query:

```
select * from MYTABLE where STRINGCOL in theVector
```

Is this possible, or do I have to "unrole" the vector manually?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible - sadly. Unroll the collection and build the query string is the way to go.